# How do I find out what HTTP headers are being used to download a file without access to the web server?

Tags: download, http, webserver, headers, web-hosting

If I do not have access to the web server configuration files, how would I know what HTTP headers are being used to download files?

I am talking about files that are downloaded by the browser, not displayed in the browser  view port.

I am aware that some tools, like Firebug (and other browser extensions), will show headers for files loaded into the browser view port (e.g. HTML pages and images) but they don't - as far as I can see - display this information for files that are downloaded.

3rd party tools would be useful, preferably free.

I know asking the web host is one answer but it's not the one I am looking for (unless it's the only one) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows I know proxomitron which allows you to see and modify all HTTP headers.

The purpose of this software is to configure your system to use it as a proxy, so every single http request can be seen and/or modified by it.

You can also use Wireshark if it's not HTTPS traffic to monitor your network traffic.

Comment: On Windows also [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) is very powerful, easy to use and free.

Comment: I used both Fiddler and Wireshark and both provided the answer I needed, thanks Robert and epingle. Wireshark is powerful and useful but a bit difficult to use. Fiddler is easier to use but a bit buggy (exception errors and did not capture Firefox traffic).